# How to sort class list by integer property?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Below I have created a list with 4 elements of type Person. I would like to sort the Person list in ascending order according to the Age property. Is there an elegant way to accomplish this with LINQ or IComparable (or something else) so I don't have to write my own algorithm from scratch?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
            people.Add(new Person("Matthew", 27));
            people.Add(new Person("Mark", 19));
            people.Add(new Person("Luke", 30));
            people.Add(new Person("John", 20));

            // How to sort list by age?

        }

        private class Person
        {
            string Name { get; set; }
            int Age { get; set; }

            public Person(string name, int age)
            {
                Name = name;
                Age = age;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, the obligatory, "let's downvote you for not knowing what exact keywords to search with to find a duplicate question"...

Comment: The Duplicate Police nail another one ... :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<Person> SortedList = people.OrderBy(o => o.Age).ToList();
```

Comment: I oppose. Although it looks "pretty", it is still inefficient both in performance and design to copy the whole list instead of sorting the existing list. @manji provided the correct answer, not this one.

Answer (score 10):

```
people.Sort((p1, p2) =>
{
  return p1.Age - p2.Age;
});
```

Comment: Linq already comes iwith that exact same code in OrderBy()

Comment: [Are you sure?](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,618)

Comment: yea, i spoke too soon , I had thought initially you had a comparison .  So you're right that it does not exist, but int already implements IComparable , so IMO just using built-in OrderBy is most  "elegant way to accomplish this"

Comment: OrderBy doesn't sort a list in-place.  You can combine it with `.ToList()` to create a new sorted list, but it doesn't sort the original list, like this solution.

Comment: I don't really understand how it works but this was the only way I could get a list to sort on an Integer field. The .OrderBy didn't work for me on an integer value.